# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server in EF 6.2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using `Entity Framework 6.2.0` with an asp.net MVC code-first approach to do a sample application.

I have enabled-migrations and update-database successfully. Consequently, the `database` `Vidly.Models.ApplicationDbContext.mdf` has been created in my Solution Explorer within the `App_Data` folder.

I have declared a class in my Models folder as below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

In my **Web.Config** file, I have added the connection string as below:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationDbContext"  connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Vidly.Models.ApplicationDbContext;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

However, when I am starting the application, I am getting the following exception :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

I have consulted similar exceptions on stackoverflow, but could not figure out what is wrong. 
Could someone advise what is wrong here please ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to connect to your LocalDB from Visual Studio Server Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have create your Database in your **App_Data** Folder but you trying to access 
sql server  that.

try this

```
<connectionstrings>
        <add name="ApplicationDbContext"  connectionstring="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Vidly.Models.ApplicationDbContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True  " providername="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionstrings>
```

Comment: Hello, 

Same exception occurs :/

Comment: <add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-[ 
Your Project Name ]-[ Your Database Name ].mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-[ Your Project Name ]-[ Your Database Name ];Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Use This 

<add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\[ Your Database Name ].mdf;Initial Catalog=[ Your Database Name ];Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is **NOT** your specific case (but it IS related to exception you are having - so added this answer for the sake of completeness)

I had the same error and the cause of the problem was that I had forgotten to add `providerName` to the connection string...

*(in my case - coppied sql string from Azure portal, manually created `connectionString` parameter in `Web.config` file and forgot to add providerName parameter, so it is not that hard to have such a mistake...)*

So if you are experiencing this type of exception, you should check if your connection string is correct / not missing provider name.